# Show all records/some records based on parameter value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have stored procedure which returns around 100 rows. One column is Category.

In SSRS, I've created DataSet related to that stored procedure. On Report body I have Tablix, which I relate to DataSet.

Now, I have additional parameter, called FilterColumn, which consist all different categories from dataset, plus one row called "All products".

How to filter tablix based on that parameter to show me whether products from specific categories or all products?

Comment: Is the parameter single or multi-valued? Is there any reason you can't filter at the stored procedure level, e.g. the data is used elsewhere in the report?

Comment: In fact, it's for the demonstration purpose, to show filter variation. Parameter is single-valued.

Comment: One more, sorry... Your parameter is called **Sorting**, but it's actually used to *filter* the Tablix. Is this correct? It seems slightly confusing.

Comment: @IanPreston Thanks for suggestion, I've corrected question text :) In fact, story is about filtering, not sorting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created some solution and worked for me:

[image]

In `Expression` field, I put first expression:

```
1.  Iif(Parameters!FilterColumn.Value = "All", 1, Fields!Category.Value)
```

In `Value` field, I put second expression:

```
2.  Iif(Parameters!FilterColumn.Value = "All", 1, Parameters!FilterColumn.Value)
```

So, when I choose "All" value in parameter, then first expression will result 1, and second expression will result 1, and i have `1 = 1` which is true for all rows, and I got all rows in table.

When I choose specific category from parameter, then in first expression result  will be `Fields!Category.Value` and in second expression will be `Parameters!FilterColumn.Value`. Simple, I got `Fields!Category.Value = Parameters!FilterColumn.Value`, or just give me rows where category is that choosen in parameter.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set up a filter similar to the following:

[image]

Where the expression is:

```
=IIf(Parameters!FilterColumn.Value = Fields!Category.Value
        or Parameters!FilterColumn.Value = "All products"
    , "Include"
    , "Exclude")
```

This matches the row *Category* based on the parameter value, or, if the value = `All products`, will include all rows.

As mentioned in the comments and the other answer, this is possible in the SP too, but since it seems to be specifically to demonstrate the functionality this should do the trick at the report level.

Comment: would this work a report set with multiple filters, but only one would be filled?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the Additional Parameter to your store procedure, so you send data that is already sorted to your report. This will avoid multiple Tablix created depending on your parameter selection.

Comment: Or you can right click on the column you want to sort on your Tablix. Tablix properties --> Select Sorting-->Column to sort.

Comment: The story isabout filtering not sorting, and confusion is because I named parameter Sorting. Now I am correcting this, sorry :)