# Looking for a way to filter out rows that contain 0 by using a parameter in SSRS Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have a parameter called "Hide Zero On Hand" with values of true and false. I need a way of applying this parameter to a field called "TotalQty". If true is chosen within the parameter, then the rows containing 0 in the field "TotalQty" will be removed. But if false is chosen, then nothing is filtered out. I'm new to SSRS and I'm not sure where to start with making this work.

Comment: There is a wealth of info and examples for this common task. Try this to start with, it's pretty simple. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tutorial-add-a-parameter-to-your-report-report-builder?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: As you wrote this question.. SO would have suggested so many answers! Yet here we are!  For one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203317/show-all-records-some-records-based-on-parameter-value